# Connect Django with Azure MS SQL Server DB using managed identity

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-managed-identity

How can I connect my Azure MS SQL Server Database to Django through managed Identity.

Currently my Django **settings.py** file looks like this :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'HPI_SI_DB',
        'HOST': 'abcengine.database.windows.net',
        'USER': 'xyz',
        'PASSWORD': '*******',
        'OPTIONS': {'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server', }
    },
    'DB2': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'HPI_SI_DB',
        'HOST': 'abcdengine.database.windows.net',
        'USER': 'xyz',
        'PASSWORD': '*******',
        'OPTIONS': {'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server', }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you check this wiki: https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django/wiki/Azure-AD-Authentication#activedirectorymsi ?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django/wiki/Azure-AD-Authentication#activedirectorymsi)

> #### ActiveDirectoryMsi
>
> To use managed identity, add `Authentication=ActiveDirectoryMsi` to `extra_params`.
>
> ```
> DATABASES = {
>   "default": {
>       "ENGINE": "mssql",
>       "NAME": "your_db",
>       "HOST": "database.windows.net",
>       "PORT": "1433",
>       "OPTIONS": {
>           "driver": "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
>           "extra_params": "Authentication=ActiveDirectoryMsi",
>       },
>   },
> }
> ```
>
> If you want to run unit test then the test database must be manually created and you need to pass in the `--keepdb` argument.
>
> If you are getting a `VIEW ANY COLUMN MASTER KEY DEFINITION permission denied in database` error run `EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'<Name>'`, replacing `<Name>` with the name of the VM in system-assigned managed identity or the name of the managed identity in user-assigned managed identity.